# send and recieve broadcast message over udp with Poco library

Tags: c++, networking, poco-libraries

I send a broadcast message over UDP using Poco DatagramSocket. when the range of IP address of sender and receiver is different(sender = 172.168.30.10 and receiver = 172.168.28.30), I can't receive a message on another side.

I try broadcasting over 255.255.255.255 and receiving over 0.0.0.0, but fail to receive it.

sender code

```cpp
    auto interfaces = Poco::Net::NetworkInterface::map();
    for (auto& interface : interfaces)
    {
      auto addressess = interface.second.addressList();
      for (auto& address : addressess)
      {
        auto ip = address.get<Poco::Net::NetworkInterface::BROADCAST_ADDRESS>();
        if (ip.isIPv4Compatible())
        {
             DatagramSocket ds(Poco::Net::AddressFamily::IPv4);
             ds.setBroadcast(true);
             ds.sendTo(message.data(), 
             message.size(),Poco::Net::SocketAddress(ip,2001));
        }
      }
    }
```

reciever code

```cpp
Poco::Net::SocketAddress ipaddress(Poco::Net::AddressFamily::IPv4,2001);
DatagramSocket ss(ipaddress);
ss.setBroadcast(true);
char buffer[4096];
int n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
std::string msg = std::string(buffer, n);
```

Comment: Can you include the code which sets `ip`?  Are you able to test with a pre-built program like `nc` (netcat) or something else to make sure your network is actually handling these packets?

Comment: Broadcasting to 255.255.255.255 has been deprecated for about 30 years. You should be using 172.168.28.255, and ensuring that your router to that subnet supports broadcasting. Multicast is a better choice all round.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I add it.

Comment: @user207421I changed the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0. how can I ensure that my router support broadcasting to that subnet?